# How can I give the blue areas an emission and crystal effect?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shader-nodes

As the title implies, I'm trying to give the blue areas these effects. I already have another material setup in the purple area so I don't want the effects to change it, just the blue. Like an ore or something. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
(Your node setup^)

This will work for a low-poly setup (which is what I think you are doing, based on your previous question)

[image]

To make the crystal material, plug a voronoi texture into a color ramp, then that one into an emission.

For a realistic glowing crystal (not stylized or lowpoly) a more complex texture setup would have to do, involving transparency, albedo, and bump maps for the crystal texture, in addition to a colorramp/emission node setup for the glowing effect.

Here's how to combine them:

1. Subdivide your object to the point that it is fairly dense (the more vertices, the better, as we will be painting on them.)
2. Select all the vertices in Edit Mode and go to 'Object Data Properties' and click the '+' to add all the vertices to a new group.
3. Make this setup of nodes for the material for the entire object: [image]
4. One of the diffuse nodes is the Principled Output from your meteorite texture, the second is the glowing texture output.
5. Go to Vertex Paint mode
6. Paint the object! One color is the glowing texture, the other is the meteorite texture. *Tip: more vertices means higher detail when painting*:[image]
   Lots of vertices^^
   [image]
   Few vertices^^

Comment: That's cool, but how do I have that effect the blue areas only? And yeah, its low poly alright. I'll add an image of my nodes as well

Comment: @Bren, I edited the answer to show how you can 'paint' multiple textures on a single mesh.

Comment: I definitely appreciate your responses, unfortunately I still have to keep this bad boy low poly, and somehow make this all happen procedurally. If you have any other solutions tho, I am absolutely listening :)

Comment: @Bren, maybe add a noise texture to the Mix Shader node instead of doing the whole vertex paint thing. That way you could have the glowing crystal texture randomly appear all over the meterorite.

Comment: (it would also keep it procedural *and* low-poly! ;)

Comment: @Bren, would that work?